# Running the same javascript functions many times, every 2 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this function:

```
function menucount(bartype, div){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:"opdate-menu="+bartype+"&bar=<?php echo $barnavn ?>",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#'+div).html(data);
            }
        });
   });
}
```

It checks for updates and displays a new number in my menu-buttons. I use it like this:

```
window.setInterval(menucount(), 2000);
```

This works.

Now I want to run this function on more buttons, so I create a 'wrapper' function and try to run it like this:

```
function wrapper(){
    menucount('manglerprint','printvip');
    menucount('manglerprint_plus','printvipplus');
    menucount('temp_vipplus','ansvipplus');
    menucount('temp_vipalm','ansvip');
}

window.setInterval(wrapper(), 2000);
```

But this doesnt work, It only runs one of the `menucount()` instances. How could I run `menucount()` many times like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the function once using `wrapper()` and is passing the value returned by it `undefined` to the `setInterval()`.

You need to pass the function reference to `setInterval()` like

```
window.setInterval(wrapper, 2000);
```

Note: Also the first example, that also will get executed only once...

Comment: Would there be a way to only load the data if it has changed?

Comment: @Bolli which function wrapper/menucount and what data